# Android Expandable RecyclerView as Tabs of viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandable

I'm trying to display 1 activity like picture below this thread.
I want to make 1 display have: 1 `viewpager`, 1 header
But I need custom header: 1 `recyclerview` expandable(please see picture), I handler clicked recyclerexpandable to `setCurrent` page make `viewpager` scroll to position follow header, now I want make when `viewpager` swipe to next page, header will charger background item (CHILD and PARENT),  but when next done child item to go to parent, old child list will close.

[image]

Comment: I follow this tutorial for make recycler expandable: http://anandbose.github.io/android_recyclerview_expandablelistview.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one as a solution :

```
 expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                           View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                    groupPosition, childPosition);
            if(your condition){

            }else if(your condition2) {

            }else{

            }
        }

   }
```

Comment: I will try it soon! Thanks @Bhuvnesh Chasta
But i thinks u wrong in here! Im using recyclerview not using expandablelistview!
Maybe u can help me make expandablelistview horizontal then i can do it